How to extract the mutations specific to cancer after variant annotation in NGS analysis
I am working on B cell lymphoma of dogs to identify the specific type of mutations related to this disease. I am performing NGS whole genome sequencing analysis. I have performed the variant annotation using ANNOVAR and received thousands of variants. I want to separate the cancer related variants among these, is there any online platforms that I can compare my variants with? OR how to proceed with this data? Could someone please help? Thanks.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

What type of variants are you looking for? (Rare vs common, SNVs vs amplifications/deletions vs fusions, etc.) And  what are you using as a control?
